# Need help with this programming problem involving flipping coins

Tags: c, algorithm

Im trying to solve the flipping coins problem on codechef.com (http://www.codechef.com/problems/FLIPCOIN/)
My code is in C, and i tested it using gcc v4.4.3 on my machine running Linux,and my program works for the sample input provided. However, on uploading to the judge i get the message "Wrong Answer".
In my program i represent the flipping of coins by the toggling of bits.I think my algorithm is correct,and im not able to come up with a case where it would fail. Below is my code. 
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank You.

```
#include <stdio.h>

long int n=0,temp,number_of_coins,number_of_inputs,bit_mask;
long int number_of_ones(long int i) //Return the number of bits set
{
   return __builtin_popcountl(i);
}
int main(void)
{
    long int ctr,lower,upper,length;
    int op;

    scanf("%ld %ld",&number_of_coins,&number_of_inputs);
    length = number_of_coins-1;
    for(ctr = 0 ; ctr < number_of_inputs;ctr++) //Main loop
    {
        scanf("%d %ld %ld",&op,&lower,&upper);
        bit_mask = ((1 << length-lower+1)-1) & ~((1 << length-upper)-1);

        if(op == 0)
        {   

            n ^= bit_mask ; //Toggle the bits in the range lower to upper

        }
        else
        {
            temp = n;
            temp &= bit_mask;
            printf("%ld\n",number_of_ones(temp)); //Print number of bits set
        }


    }



    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the website expects your program to take all lines of input at once before printing the output?

Comment: You think that a function named `__builtin_popcountl` is portable?

Comment: I think thats not the case because i have submitted some solutions before where i didnt take all input beforehand.The program is supposed to read from the input stream and write to the output stream @Borealid : The online judge is using gcc v4.3.2. Can this cause a problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you use a bit sequence stored in a `long int` to represent the coins, your code won't work with more than 32 coins (or however many bits are in a `long`). The site specifies that there can be up to 100000 coins though.

Comment: This is right. Either you can track 10000 bits manually and be huge memory hog, or you can use a linked list of intervals.

Comment: @mathepic: "or you can use a linked list of intervals" ... and be a huge memory hog for sequences like 010101010101

Comment: Thats a good point, but I think on average the linked list will take less memory... Not quite sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could someone please explain, how would i represent the following 3 steps using a linked list of intervals 1) bits from index 0 to index 99999 get flipped 2) Then bits from index 400 to index 500 get flipped 3)Finally,bits from index 4 to index 10 get flipped.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a problem with the CodeChef method of checking the results, as i have gotten the same answer as well. There is not a problem with your code.